# Java Image Editor with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, editor

I need an image editor for java.Which basically uses a JQuery for client side events.Just checking if any one can provide any suggestion for some opensource program which can be easily integrated to existing website.

Comment: Image editor for java or javascript?

Comment: I need it for Web basically.To be used with jsp pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try imageJ:

[imageJ download](http://www.ansci.wisc.edu/equine/parrish/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is repository for Litha-Paint editor: https://svn.codehaus.org/litha-paint/
It doesn't require canvas, so it works even with old browsers (like IE6)